Tu, Exercise 18.5
In Exercise 18.5 Tu asks the reader to find the transition formula of a 2-form on an n-manifold. He provides the formula below before asking the reader to find $a_ij$ in terms of $b_{kl}$
$\omega = \sum_{i<j } a_{ij } dx^i \wedge dx^j = \sum_{k<l} b_{kl } dy^k \wedge dy^l$
My answer is that
$a_{ij} = \sum_{k<l} b_{kl} \frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial y^l}{\partial x^i} $
I found this by applying $(e_i,e_j)$ to the LHS and applying $( \frac{\partial y^\alpha}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^\alpha}, \frac{\partial y^\beta}{\partial x^j} \frac{\partial}{\partial y^\beta})$ to the RHS.
If not for the $i<j$ restriction on the sum of the RHS of my answer, $b_{kl}$ could found in terms of a's with the inverse Jacobians. However, this isn't true anymore. Thus, my question is, is there a way to find $b_{kl}$ from this answer or another, potentially cleaner, way to find $b_{kl}$.

I would try to derive this without applying the $2$-form to vectors. Just write $dy^k = \sum \frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^i}dx^i$ and substitute.  The $i<j$ restriction may not be worth the trouble; if necessary, sum over all $k,l$, let $b_{lk} = -b_{kl}$ and put in a factor of $1/2$. People often are too obsessed with evaluating on tangent vectors when they calculate with differential forms.

Thanks for commenting @TedShifrin. This is the approach I started with. However, I am running into difficulty with this approach. Specifically, I am having trouble figuring out how to get back to the antisymmetric basis. Forgetting about the a's for a minute: $dy^i \wedge dy^j = \sum_{alternating, in, l, and, k} \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^l} dx^i \otimes dx^j$.

Writing the comment above, I am realizing I can write $dy^i \wedge dy^j = \sum_{i<j} ( \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^l} - \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^l} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^k} ) dx^i \wedge dx^j$. Does this make sense? @TedShifrin

Absolutely correct. Just take wedge product in the first place.
